# Sort table with AJAX jquery

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, twitter-bootstrap

I'm trying to sort my table with the JS tablesort, who is populate with JSON, and the follow error appear to me

> "Cannot read property '0' of undefined"

Looks like the tablesort dont recognize the ajax data.

This is my jquery

```
 $.get(url, function(response){

    serverResponse = response;

    for(i in response.content){

        totalclientes++;

        var status = response.content[i].LojaStatus;
            if(status == 0){
                LojaStatus = "Ativo";
                botao = '\ ' +
                    '<div class = "btn-group"> <button type = "button" class = "btn btn-primary" onclick="redirect(' + response.content[i].LojaId + ')" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">Editar</button>       <button type = "button" class = "btn btn-primary dropdown-toggle" data-toggle = "dropdown"> <span class = "caret"></span> <span class = "sr-only">Toggle Dropdown</span> </button> <ul class = "dropdown-menu" role = "menu"> <li><a href = "javascript:deletar(' + response.content[i].LojaId + ')">Desativar</a></li> <li><a href = "http://amovitrine.devmaker.com.br/relatorioloja.php?LojaId='+ response.content[i].LojaId +'">Relatorio</a></li> </ul> </div>';
            }else{
                LojaStatus = "Inativo";
                botao = '\ ' +
                    '<div class = "btn-group"> <button type = "button" class = "btn btn-primary" onclick="redirect('+response.content[i].LojaId+')" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">Editar</button>       <button type = "button" class = "btn btn-primary dropdown-toggle" data-toggle = "dropdown"> <span class = "caret"></span> <span class = "sr-only">Toggle Dropdown</span> </button> <ul class = "dropdown-menu" role = "menu"> <li><a href = "javascript:ativar('+response.content[i].LojaId+')">Ativar</a></li><li><a href = "http://amovitrine.devmaker.com.br/relatorioloja.php?LojaId='+ response.content[i].LojaId +'">Relatorio</a></li> </ul> </div>';
            }

        var botao =


            data +='\
        <tr>\
            <td>'+response.content[i].LojaNome+'</td>\
            <td>'+response.content[i].LojaBairro+'</td>\
            <td>'+response.content[i].LojaTelefone1+'</td>\
            <td>'+LojaStatus+'</td>\
            <td>'+response.content[i].PlanoNome+'</td>\
            <td>'+response.content[i].LojaInicioPlano+'</td>\
            <td>'+response.content[i].LojaFimPlano+'</td>\
            <td>'+botao+'</td>\
        </tr>';
    }

    $('#corpotabela').empty();
    $('#corpotabela').append(data);
```

This is my table

```
 <table class="table table-bordered table-hover" id="table">
            <thead style="border: 1px solid #ddd;" >
            <tr style="cursor: pointer;">
                <th>Nome</th>
                <th>Bairro</th>
                <th>Telefone</th>
                <th>Status</th>
                <th>Plano</th>
                <th>Data Inicio</th>
                <th>Data Fim</th>
                <th>Ações</th>
            </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody id="corpotabela">

            </tbody>
        </table>
```

Any suggestions?

*EDIT
    [This is my table right now](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IjNNx.jpg)

*EDIT 2

[this is a example of object in my response](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2tDzT.jpg)

**EDIT 3 - THE SOLUTION**

Basically I was using the tablesorter out of the getData function, who populate me table.

So, i apply the tablesorter after `$('#corpotabela').append(data);` line and it works great.

Comment: Which line of code is generating the error?

Comment: the reason you would get that is if you're accessing 0 or a variable that is not defined. Meaning, you're expecting data to be somewhere but it is not. try some `console.log`s to se what data comes back

Comment: @CindyMeister jquery.tablesorter.js:600

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend you to check if the response you're getting is actualy JSON.
Then, try using Firebug to get concrete error and post it here.

Comment: There's still a posibility the data is inconsistent or the syntax is broken, may be even headers, as long as you're not parsing JSON. Take a look at Network tab or `console.log` the response. And the Firebug error message really could help with JS.

Comment: In the firebug looks ok, but chrome's console still showing me the error "Cannot read property '0' of undefined" or "Cannot read property '1' of undefined" etc for every collumn

Comment: Could you please update your question with example of response you're getting from service?

Comment: [It's not hard to earn enough rep to make comments.](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead)

Comment: @LuanGabriel, If I've reprodused your code right, the only thing that gives me trouble is this part: `for (i in response)` which you referring later to as a key in `content[i]`, so it seems i is equals to `"content"` at this moment. Try to make `console.log(i)` right before `for`-sentence and post here what it will output.

Comment: @Switcher I dont get it but, the follow error occurred (expected) "Uncaught ReferenceError: i is not defined"

Comment: @LuanGabriel https://jsfiddle.net/sf8po9xn take a look at my variation, it works pretty well in Chrome (not via fiddle however)